# Can Qt on Windows and Qt on Linux work with same source code?

Tags: qt, cross-platform

Since Qt is a cross-platform application framework, is that mean a single Qt project or source code can be compiled on both platform? Say, if I have dual boot installed, like Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint 17. Both are 64 bit. If I install Qt on both platform, will it gonna work with a single project?

Comment: Yes. Almost all the time.  Look at the startling array of stock examples offered by Qt in the `Welcome > Examples` tab, and they all run on Mac, Linux and Windows with native look, feel and performance.

Comment: So why Qt on windows need to have mingw32 compiler and msvc compiler?

Comment: MingW is a port of gcc/g++ for windows.  It has a lot of Windows library calls available, too, but it is not binary compatible with all libraries that are out there for windows.  MSVC is the compiler from Microsoft, and it has its own benefits and drawbacks. Probably the biggest drawback of MSVC is half the time you need to make sure that the deployment computer has the latest `Visual C++ Redistributables on the computer` (with the correct year and architecture) while MingW doesn't have that requirement.